# JavaScript - get one or more smallest value(s) in the array, even if array size is 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am sorry if my question is stupid. I have been trying very hard to get smallest value(s) in the array using JavaScript, even if array size is 1. For example, if I have the array consists of the elements [1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2], I would like to know that the smallest values are 1,1,1,2,3,4, in this order. However, I cannot get the desired result. Can someone please help me?

I have the following code snippet:

```js
var nearestBoothIndex = 0;
var arrDistanceToThisBooth = [1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var distanceToThisBoothLength = arrDistanceToThisBooth.length;
var nearestBooth = arrDistanceToThisBooth[0]

for (var a = 0; a < distanceToThisBoothLength; a++) {

  if (arrDistanceToThisBooth.length == 1) {
    nearestBooth = arrDistanceToThisBooth[0];
    alert("nearest booth " + nearestBooth);
  }


  for (var b = 1; b < arrDistanceToThisBooth.length; b++) {
    if (arrDistanceToThisBooth[b] <= nearestBooth) {

      nearestBooth = arrDistanceToThisBooth[b]
      alert("nearest booth " + nearestBooth);
      nearestBoothIndex = b;

    } else if (arrDistanceToThisBooth.length == 2 && (nearestBooth < arrDistanceToThisBooth[b])) {
      nearestBooth = nearestBooth
      nearestBoothIndex = 0;
      alert("nearest booth " + nearestBooth);
    }
  }

  var elementRemoved = arrDistanceToThisBooth.splice(nearestBoothIndex, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `sort()` the `array`?

Comment: Try with `Array.sort`, looks like that's what you actually want.

Comment: Omg I am so stupid

Comment: But is there a way to get the original index of the array after sorting out?

Comment: To get the original index after sorting, I would do something like this: `arr.map(function(item, index){ return {item:item, index: index}}).sort(function(a,b){ return a.item - b.item});` This will give you an array of `object`s that are sorted based on value but it also keeps track of the original index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort the array while also storing the original index, you will have to store the indexes in an object, or turn each value into an object that remembers its index, and then use a custom sort comparator.

```js
function sortKeepingIndexes(values) {
  return values
    .map(function(val, i) { return { value: val, index: i }; })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });
}

var sorted = sortKeepingIndexes([1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2]);
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The index of the smallest value would be at `sorted[0].index`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, very helpful. But can you teach me how I could access the object?

Comment: I'm not sure in what way you need to access it. Are you talking about [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)?

Comment: for example, I would like to get the original index of the value "1". The answer should give me the values 0,1,4. If i want to get the original index of the value "4", the answer should give me the value 3.

Comment: What I want is, e.g if I pass in a parameter of values "1", it would return me the index

Comment: @Antoni `sorted.find(obj => obj.value === 1).index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134935/discussion-between-antoni-and-4castle).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [10, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1];
var arrCopy = arr.slice();

arrCopy.sort(function(a,b){
  return a - b;
});

alert(arr + '\n' + arrCopy);
```

might be something you need

Answer (score 0):

Well sorting the array via `Array.sort` would mutate the array. That sometimes is not the desired result. It seems that is the result you want in this particular case but just FYI.

You could also use `underscore` or `lodash` libs ... both have `_.min` and `_.max` methods (as well as tons of other useful methods) that would give you the result without mutating the array.

Comment: `array.slice().sort()` will work without mutating and you don't need a lib for it.

Comment: I would argue that that is probably not the most performant way to do this (since now you copy the array and then you sort it) ... but you are absolutely right it would avoid the mutation and you can skip the lib there is no question. Good point.

Comment: @Akrion It's impossible to sort the array without either mutating or making a copy first. `_.min` and `_.max` will only get a single value, so they don't have the right result.